# How to Get Variable from inside a function (used in Ajax call)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Greetings I have an ajax call which:

1. Gets an xml file of posts
2. Populates a 2d Array of post info (text and link)

What I need next is to get at the Array to do the next steps, but I cannot get at it.

Scope issue? Ajax issue?

please advise.

```
// create the link
var posts_href = 'get-posts.php';

// Create XHR Object
function getHTTPObject(){
    var xhr = false;
    // test if standards based
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try{
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e){
                xhr = false;
            } 
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}

// Grab File ASYCHRONOUSLY
function grabFile(file){
    // create a new instance of the xhr object
    var request = getHTTPObject();

    // if successful, initiate ajax request
    if(request){
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            parseResponseXML(request);

        };

        request.open("GET",file,true);
        request.send(null);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// make the ajax call
grabFile(posts_href);

// create the responseXML function
function parseResponseXML(req){
    if(req.readyState == 4){
        if(req.status == 200 || req.status == 304){
            var textArray = [];
            var posts = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('post');

            // create array to hold the posts (strings)     
            textArray = new Array(posts.length);

            for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++){

                var post_text, text, post_link, details_link;

                // get the post info
                post_text = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('text');
                text = post_text[0].firstChild.nodeValue

                post_link = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('details_link');
                if(post_link[0].firstChild != null){
                    details_link = post_link[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                } else {
                    details_link = "";
                }

                // add post to textArray
                textArray[i] = new Array(text, details_link);
                // console.log(textArray[i]);

            }   // end for..loop                
        }       // end if(req.status)
    }           // end if(req.readyState)   
}               // end parseResponseXML()


// get the value of textArray from the function ->THIS FAILS
console.log(textArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an ajax issue. Ajax is asynchronous. Whatever "next steps" that depend on `textArray` need to be done **in the callback.** You can modify `parseResponseXML` to receive an arbitrary callback that it should pass the results array to:

```
function parseResponseXML(req, callback) {
    // same as original implementation above
    // then,
    callback(textArray);
}
```

Then you'd use it something like this:

```
function doAfterParse(textArray) {
    console.log(textArray);
}

// snip...
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    parseResponseXML(request, doAfterParse);
};
```

Comment: I see it now. very cool. thanks! will put in some more study on this issue.